# Socket Error Connecting to Nanopool with xmr-stak

Tags: xmr-stak-amd

I've had a miner running for about a week now with no problem, but this morning it just started reporting the following error:

```
SOCKET ERROR - [xmr-eu1.nanopool.org:14444] CONNECT error: GetAddrInfo: No such host is known
```

I have no idea whats causing it, but my machine can connect to the internet just fine and resolve the pool website. I also rebooted and tried flushing the dns which have done nothing.

I also have a second miner on the same network thats working just fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That indeed looks like a DNS error. One thing you can try is swapping the FQDN with the IP address to confirm it's somewhere in the DNS resolution. I've had to do that on a couple large pools.

In other words `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:14444`

Comment: In the end I did exactly what you suggested and it worked just fine with the IP address. Must be some temporary DNS issue

Comment: Awesome to hear @MattWhetton If you ever need a backup pool, please consider mine: https://mon.gulfcoastmining.com - it's new so it has the associated "first block" growing pains!